SQLAlchemy database session is not reset after each test
I have this TestRunner base class mostly following their example:
import unittest

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from compliance.takedowns.data.models import Base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
SessionFactory = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)  # Initial schema setup


class TakedownsDBInternalTestRunner(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.engine = engine

    def setUp(self):
        self.connection = self.engine.connect()
        self.trans = self.connection.begin()
        self.session = SessionFactory

        self.nested = self.connection.begin_nested()

        @listens_for(self.session, "after_transaction_end")
        def end_savepoint(session, transaction):
            assert self.nested is not None
            if not self.nested.is_active:
                self.nested = self.connection.begin_nested()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.session.close()
        self.trans.rollback()
        self.connection.close()


But I'm noticing I'm getting referential integrity errors between my tests?
class RequestTests(TakedownsDBInternalTestRunner):
    def test_one(self):
        request = create_base_request()
        self.session.add(request)
        self.session.commit()

        result = self.session.query(Request).all()
        self.assertEqual(len(result), 1)

    def test_two(self):
        request = create_base_request()
        self.session.add(request)
        self.session.commit()

        result = self.session.query(Request).all()
        self.assertEqual(len(result), 2)


This is the error I get:
========================================================================================================= short test summary info =========================================================================================================
FAILED test_request.py::RequestTests::test_two - AssertionError: 1 != 2
FAILED test_request.py::RequestTests::test_one - AssertionError: 2 != 1


Are you actually using sqlalchemy 1.4?  Or are you using the 2 series?

The only issue I can imagine is the importing Base from some other module. There could be multiple session created without a proper binding which can cause rollback to malfunction. Declare a new base with test models to properly isolated the test environment. If that solve the issue we may debug the rest
We can also explore library like model-bakery which might help us isolating our model although I'm not sure about it

This is for sqlalchemy 1.4
I think you need to bind the session to the connection you make instead of letting it pool one from engine because it is probably just getting a new connection.
Use connection you make.
self.session = Session(bind=self.connection)

You might be able to use something like configure to use a new bind if you have to use the same scoped session. 1.4 docs: sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session.configure
self.session = SessionFactory
self.session.configure(bind=self.connection)

